# Jquery validation collide with HTML validation

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I want to use jquery validation for simple form using built-in validation method like required and email.

Here is my form

```
<form id="setup-company" class="form-horizontal form-rest validator" action="{{$updatePath}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="font-size: 12px;text-transform:uppercase">Nama Institusi *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$company->name}}" style="width: 100%;" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abbreviation" class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="font-size: 12px;text-transform:uppercase">Singkatan</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="abbreviation" value="{{$company->abbreviation}}" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="font-size: 12px;text-transform:uppercase">No. Telp</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" minlength="10" maxlength="12" name="phone" value="{{$company->phone}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="font-size: 12px;text-transform:uppercase">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$company->email}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button style="float:right;" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-raised rippler rippler-inverse edit-row">
        SIMPAN
    </button>
</form>
```

In the javascript, I initiate jquery validation like this.

```
 $('.form-rest').unbind().submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        // check if the input is valid
        if (!$form.valid())
            return false;
});
```

But when I try it, it shows HTML validation like this

[image]

When I fill invalid input for phone (which is third input), it seems jquery validation working properly. And when I try to fill blank input for first input, the error message came from jquery validation like this.

[image]

Whats the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

It's totally fine to have the `required` attribute. You just have to tell the browser that you want to skip the default validation by adding the `novalidate` attribute to the form element.

> The novalidate attribute is a boolean attribute.
> When present, it specifies that the form-data (input) should not be validated when submitted.